# Install Ubuntu Touch 14.10 on Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100

Tags: ubuntu-touch

como estan? mi consulta es la siguiente, quisiera saber si es posible instalar Ubuntu Touch 14.10 en un Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100.

Muchas gracias!

Hi! how are you? My question is this, I wonder if it is possible to install Ubuntu 14.10 on a Touch Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It was not released for S2, no it is not available.  Reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices